# relative path in chrome polymer 3 IIS

Tags: polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

I updated my project from Polymer-2.x to Polymer-3.x and now, when I just open my index,html in my browser I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".'

I enabled the relative path support in chrome but it still does not work.

With `polymer serve` it works fine, but I need it to work via IIS because it refers its url in its code and I have routing to do with it. So localhost is not an option for me.

Is there a way, so I can get it work without `polymer serve`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the `polymer serve`-command replaces npm-paths (e.g. `@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js`) with relative paths (e.g. `../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js`) to serve these files. So without that command, your browser does not know where the files are located.

To build a polymer project for production the `polymer-cli` has a command called `polymer build` to replace these paths automatically and that should solve your problem. Additionally that helpful command may bundle the project and minify your files. Just have a look at the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli-commands#build)

Alternatively you could just replace them manually with relative paths.